# Why can't PuTTy login to server after sshd_config "PermitRootLogin: no" change?

Tags: ssh, security, login

I following these steps to improve more security in my webserver: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuIYabZS3ow

I set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

But now I can't login through PuTTY!

I get: "Network error: Connection refused"

I create a new user non-root with sudo privileges, but still can't login after that change, and root user too can't login, I get the same error for both after change to "PermitRootLogin no"...

How can I change it without get that problem?

Comment: Nice video guide there - but very ssh-centric, It would have been nice though if they had pointed to some of their own references for Putty users. /shrug

Comment: Did you, perhaps, fail to start SSH again after making the configuration change?  "Connection Refused" means "SSH isn't running" or "there's a firewall in the way".

Comment: I follow the video so many times, and I create droplets of test...

And my recent droplet I don't make the SSH setup showed in video tutorial, i don't create keys SSH, only set the sshd_config file for disable root login and grant privileges sudo to non-root user for login with that user...

Now I don't have SSH Keys, I have only that setting:

_ PermitRootLogin no_

And I get:

   _"Network error: Connection refused"_

I enter in Console in web and I get set "PermitRootLogin yes" again and back works.. Then... How can I set to don't login with root without problem?

Comment: After making the change and restarting sshd is sshd actually running ? Use `netstat -tunlp | grep :22` to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that putty by default use the DSA algorithm to generate and use keys. But to connect to your server, your server need a RSA type key.

So you need to :

1) Generate RSA keys on your computer;
2) convert your RSA key using your putty client.

A good way would be like explained in this site (!!! instructions should be adapted !!! no copy-paste ;) ) : https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk40379

Comment: The connection refused message generally means that nothing is listening on the relevant IP:Port and has nothing to do with key formats.

Comment: Another possibility is that the firewall is blocking acces

Comment: Firewalls generally don't elicit the connection refused message.

Answer (score -2):

Be aware that Putty uses a little different format for it's keys. See this page for a tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-ssh-keys-with-putty-to-connect-to-a-vps

Edit:  **If you have the SSH private key on your local computer**, you can load it into PuttyGen and output a PPK from it so you may not be locked out of your server.

Comment: How is an incorrect key format going to cause the server to refuse connections?